# Tcp/IP listener parsing xml string output advice(code provided just not working as it should)

Tags: c#, xml, websocket, console-application

I would like advice on how to fix this code. It's a tcp/ip listener

```
requestCount = requestCount + 1;
NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[1000025];
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
string dataFromClient =       System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
 dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));


var rap= XDocument.Parse(dataFromClient)
.Descendants("gag")
 .Select(n => new {
     re= n.Element("re").Value,
           we= n.Element("we").Value
 }).ToString();

Console.WriteLine(" >> Data from client : " + rap);
string serverResponse = "Last Message from client :"  + dataFromClient;
Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
networkStream.Flush();
Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);
```

that listens  for a string like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" >
 <tt>
            <gag>
                            <re>monkey</re>
                            <we>chicken</we>
            </gag>
            <sap>
                            <re>monkey</re>
                            <we>chicken</we>
            </sap>
</tt>
```

i am attempting to show the output as only monkey and chicken in the console any advice will be appreciated i still get the whole string please dont post any answers only in comments

thank you very much

Comment: It looks like you should already be getting the right value. I very much doubt that it's really showing you "the whole string" in the console. Having said that, the way you're reading from the socket leaves a lot to be desired - you're calling `Read` *once*, and assuming that everything will be read in a single call. You're also assuming that the data will never contain a `$`, and will always be ASCII. That *may* be appropriate in your current data, but it's a very brittle approach.

Comment: "it will work" - only if you're *very* lucky. As for why you're getting back the same data you sent - you're ignoring `rap` entirely, and just sending `dataFromClient`. How did you expect that to perform any *replacement* anywhere?

Comment: We don't have nearly enough context - but if you're trying to create a message-oriented protocol, I would urge you to consider using a length-prefix solution (so you write the length of the data, then the data, then the length of the next message, etc). It's much easier to read the data reliably that way.

Comment: Basically you need to start from scratch to get this working properly, IMO. You also need to separate out the "what I want to do with the document when I've read it" from the "how I read the document" parts. It's still not even clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well you've already got a query to *find* the `re` and `we` values. You're just ignoring it afterwards. Sorry, but we really can't help with such vague requirements.

Comment: You've already *got* the values. Iterate over `rap` and you'll see them: `foreach (var item in rap) { Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.re, item.we); }`

Comment: You shouldn't post confidential code here. It will be under the CC-BY-SA license then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[1000025];
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
string dataFromClient =       System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
```

Oh, let me count the problems:

- a huge buffer - not sure why; not *wrong* per se, but almost certainly inadviseable
- not checking the reply from `Read` - that's a huge problem; how much data did it read?
- not looping to either read *all* the data, or to read a *frame* (logical message) of data
- assuming ASCII - well, maybe it is ASCII; personally I'd just buffer the bytes, though

I *suspect* you could do (assuming the client *closes their outbound socket after send*):

```
// *remove* all the `Read` code etc
// ...
var rap= XDocument.Load(networkStream) // then as before
```

and it would all work beautifully.

If the client does *not* close their outbound socket after send, you're going to have a much harder time of it.

Edit: as Jon notes - you'll need to actually *use `rap`* for it to do something *useful*.

Comment: hello Marc thanks hahaha i know it leaves alot to be desired lol i will need to delete this post sadly or edit my question code

Comment: @Wolf wait... do you actually *mean* websockets? Because if so: websockets has a framing protocol (well, actually two different framing protocols, if you want to offer full backwards compatibility). If it is websockets, you *can't treat it as vanilla sockets*. Websockets is a protocol *on top of* the socket transport.

Comment: @Wolf k, stop; to read websocket data you *either* need to implement the entire web-socket protocol(s), *or* use an existing library that will simply give you the messages and allow you to send messages. If you aren't *very* sure of sockets, I strongly advise using a library.

Comment: @Wolf to emphasize just how bad an idea that is: client-to-server comms under rfc6455 (the websocket protocol) are meant to be **masked** (random xor applied to the byte-stream). That means that the **only** way your current code can work is a: if the client is broken and isn't implementing the specification correctly, or b: a client that is using the **obsolete** hybi-00 / hixie-76 specification. For a compliant rfc6455 client you would need all the websocket-aware code to unscramble the byte-stream. Also: in a binary protocol (rfc6455 is not text) looking for sentinel values is really risky.

Comment: @Wolf if, as you are saying, this really is web-sockets, then the only advice I am happy to offer is "use a web-socket library". I'm sorry that isn't a trivial 2-hour thing, but anything else is going to be so horribly horribly broken that I can't advise it. If you are happy that this is hybi-00/hixie=76 *only*, then you could lookup the start/end sentinel values and use those to build a frame, but please let me be clear: this is really, really bad - and won't help with *any* recent clients (since they don't talk that protocol)

Comment: @Wolf or perhaps you have something to say *why* this isn't a 2-hour fix ;p

Comment: @March now i come to the part that sucks i need to delete this question ...feel bad but i must

Comment: @Wolf one of the main points of stackoverflow is that a question can help more than the one person. It is ... quite, erm, *controversial* (under-statement) to take a lot of time from people and then burn everything around you...

Comment: *sigh *i thought you might say something like that :( thanks for the help                     ...edit rolled back

Comment: will you please elaborate on your previous comment about why this is not a 2 hour fix

Comment: @Wolf plugging in a library to correctly decode a complex protocol, and testing it fully etc, is not a trivial thing, even if the library already exists